# Image reload out of cache

Tags: image, caching

I have some pack of images. I am rotate them on the server side, they keep the same name and to make them visible i am adding ?rand() after rotation. It is working on small images but on huge ones it's not, i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i figure it out. I just made different url completelly, add `/:junk` to it and it worked out.